# Error with texture loading using assimp

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I'm having a weird problem when I'm trying to load a texture using assimp library. Example:
I have this piece of code, which loads the corresponding texture image

```
if (mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE) > 0) {
        ...
    std::cout << "Loading texture file: " << textureName << std::endl;
    ...
}
else {
    std::cout << "No texture image being imported " << std::endl;
}
```

where mat is a *const aiMaterial* type.

Now, when I'm trying to load an "name".obj file with a corresponding "name".mtl file, where the mtl file is

```
Blender MTL File: 'asteroid2.blend'
Material Count: 1

newmtl Material.001
Ns ...
Ka ...
Kd ...
Ks ...
Ni ..
d ...
illum ...
map_Kd asteroid.jpg
map_Bump asteroid.jpg
```

everything works as it should (provided I have a asteroid.jpg in the folder). It works even when I change the image name to a different image I have in the folder.

However, I did not make this model myself. When I try to load a model I made myself (the model itself loads with no problem), with a correct mtl file and existing jpg, the assimp loader goes immidiately into the "No texture image being imported" and no texture loads. And that's the part I don't understand.

I made the model in Blender, put a material and a texture image on it, and the mtl should be fine too:

```
Blender MTL File: 'Tree1_1.blend'
Material Count: 1

newmtl Material.001
Ns ...
Ka ...
Kd ...
Ks ...
Ni ...
d ...
illum ...

map_Bump tree1.jpg
map_Kd tree1.jpg
```

The image tree1.jpg is in the same folder.

I can't seem the figure out where the problem is. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

SOLVED: The obj file was not exported correctly, and the obj file was not linked with the mtl file (same name is not enough, the mtl name has to be defined in obj source code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file )

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to tell without seeing minimal example. Can you add full `mtl` file and minimal `obj` (e.g. single plane)? Does other things like material colour are getting correctly loaded?

Comment: I managed to find the error, the obj was not linked with the mtl correctly, but thanks for help anyways ;-)